# Sharp lower bound for the tail of Chi-squared distribution

Tags: pr.probability

Let $X_n$ be a chi-squared random variable with $n$ degrees of freedom.  What are the sharpest known lower bounds on the tails of its distribution?  Specifically, I am looking for the lower bounds in the form:

$$P(X_n-n\geq f_1(x)\sqrt{n}+g_1(x))\geq \exp(-x)$$
$$P(n-X_n\geq f_2(x)\sqrt{n}+g_2(x))\geq \exp(-x)$$

for some $f_1(x)>0$, $f_2(x)>0$, and $g_1(x)\geq0$, $g_2(x)\geq0$.

Basically, I am wondering if the lower-bound "equivalent" of the following upper bounds from [Massart and Laurent](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-28/issue-5/Adaptive-estimation-of-a-quadratic-functional-by-model-selection/10.1214/aos/1015957395.full) (see Lemma 1 on page 1325) exist:

$$P(X_n-n\geq 2\sqrt{xn}+2x)\leq\exp(-x)$$
$$P(n-X_n\geq 2\sqrt{xn})\leq\exp(-x)$$

I tried Cramer-Chernoff Theorem (i.e. Theorem 1 in [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160116161446/http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/%7Esrikant/ECE567/Fall09/cramer-many-sources.pdf)), but the lower bound isn't sharp enough...

Comment: The left hand side of the second Massart-Laurent inequality above is zero if $x\ge n/4$, hence can't be bounded from below by an eponential function.

Answer (score 3):

This is not quite the form you requested. But if your goal was to control chi-squared left tails, I have found these lower bounds helpful.

**For $X_1 \sim \chi^2_1$:**

Let $Z \sim N(0,1)$, so that $Z/\sqrt{2} \sim N(0, 1/2)$.
For $x>0$, we have $\text{erf}(x) = P\left(|Z/\sqrt{2}| \leq x\right) = P(X_1 \leq 2x)$.

Apply [this bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/proving-sqrt1-x2-ge-operatornameerf-sqrt-log-x) or [this refinement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6908/proving-1-exp-4x2-pi-ge-texterfx2): $\text{erf}(x) \leq \sqrt{1-\exp(-4x^2/\pi)}$.

Then $P(X_1 \geq y) \geq 1- \sqrt{1-\exp(-2y/\pi)}$ for $y>0$.

**For $X_2 \sim \chi^2_2$:**

Directly from the [chi-squared CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) for $n=2$, we see that $P(X_2 \geq x) = e^{-x/2}$.

Also, since the chi-squared distribution shifts right as the df increases, $P(X_n \geq x) \geq e^{-x/2}$ for $n\geq 2$.

**For other $n$:**

See [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122868/what-is-the-order-of-the-lower-tail-of-a-chi-squared-distribution) to another question.

Answer (score 1):

You should quantify the range of $x$ that you are interested in. For example, for $1<<x<<\sqrt{n}$ you should be in the moderate deviations regime, and you could give lower bounds by performing 
the appropriate $n$-dependent change of measure and computing sharp asymptotics.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can find your answer in this link:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4816/what-are-the-sharpest-known-tail-bounds-for-chi-k2-distributed-variables

Comment: I had somehow the impression that the question is about possible lower bounds...

Comment: @AndrasBatkai is correct. I obtained the upper bounds that I put in the statement of my question from the paper cited in that response on stats.SE that you put in your answer. I may have even gotten the reference from that answer (which prompted my question), so I should probably link the two...