# Anti-concentration: upper bound for $P(\sup_{a \in \mathbb S_{n-1}}\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2Z_i^2 \ge \epsilon)$

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, measure-concentration

Let $\mathbb S_{n-1}$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$ and $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ be a i.i.d sample from $\mathcal N(0, 1)$.

## Question

Given $\epsilon > 0$ (may be assumed to be very small), what is a reasonable **upper bound** for the tail probability $P(\sup_{a \in \mathbb S_{n-1}}\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2z_i^2 \ge \epsilon)$ ?

## Observations

- Using ideas from [this other answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/95108/78539) (MO link), one can establish the **non-uniform** anti-concentration bound: $P(\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2z_i^2 \le \epsilon) \le \sqrt{e\epsilon}$ for all $a \in \mathbb S_{n-1}$.
- The uniform analogue is another story. May be one can use covering numbers ?

Comment: Doesn't $\sup_{a \in \mathbb S_{n-1}}\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2Z_i^2 = \max_{1 \le i \le n} Z_i^2$?  So this question is really just about the largest order statistic of a $\chi^2$ sample.

Comment: Thanks @NateEldredge. 1 or 2 minutes ago, I came up a similar understanding of the problem (after liking it to best response strategy, or max of linear form over probability simplex) :)

Comment: It also tells you that the probability is $1 - F(\epsilon)^n$ where $F$ is the cdf of $\chi^2$ with 1 degree of freedom.  And there should be plenty of good bounds for $F$.

Comment: Yes indeed, and the best known one is due to Massart et al.

Comment: Lemma 1 of https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1015957395.

Comment: At this point, may be I should just close the question. Not sure it could have any general interest.

Comment: I'd suggest you just post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: OK, I've posted an answer. Thanks for the kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by a user (Nate Eldgredge) in the comments under the question,

$$
P\left(\sup_{a \in \mathbb S_{n-1}}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2Z_i^2 \ge \epsilon\right) = P\left(\max_{1 \le i \le n}Z_i^2 \ge \epsilon\right) = 1-P(Z_1^2 \le \epsilon)^n = 1-P(\chi^2 \le \epsilon)^n.
$$
One can then invoke standard tail bounds for chi-squared variables (e.g exponential-type tail bound established in [Lemma 1 of this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1015957395)), to finish the problem.