# Can we prove the following anti-concentration inequality of polynomials of square Gaussian variables?

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, measure-concentration

Following this question [Anti-concentration of Gaussian quadratic form](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95096/anti-concentration-of-gaussian-quadratic-form). We have the following inequality:

> Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ denote i.i.d. standard Gaussian random variables. For every $\epsilon>0$ and real number $a_1,\dots, a_n>0$, we get
> $$
> \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_ia_iX_i^2\le\epsilon\sum_ia_i\right)\le\sqrt{e\epsilon}
> $$

In my setting, let $A=\{a_{ij}\}_{1\le i,j\le n}$ be an $n$ by $n$ normalized Gaussian random matrix with $E[a_{ij}]=0$ and $E[a_{ij}^2]=1/n$. Ordering its eigenvalues by $\lambda_1\le \lambda_2\le \cdots \lambda_n$ with corresponding eigenvectors $v_1,\dots, v_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Here $\lambda_i$ follows the semi-circle law.

Let $X_1,\dots, X_n$ be $n$ i.i.d. Gaussian random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Assume that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2=n$. I want to upper bound the function
$$
L(t):=\frac{a_1X_1}{\sqrt{\sum_i a^2_iX^2_i}}
$$
where $a_i=e^{-2\lambda_i t}$ for $t>0$.

Indeed, I try to answer the following question:

> **Question: can we upper bound this one to solve this question: For $\epsilon>0$, define $\tau:=\inf_{t\ge 0}\{L\ge \epsilon\}$ Show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} P(\tau\ge n^{2/3})=1. $$**

---

I can just apply the inequality in that question. Then for any $\epsilon>0$,
$$\quad \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2a_i^2 \le \epsilon\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2|\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\right)\le \sqrt{e\epsilon}\quad $$

Moreover, based on the above inequality, taking $\epsilon=1/n^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha>0$, we get the following concentration inequality
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2a_i^2 \le n^{-\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2|\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\right)\le \sqrt{en^{-\alpha}}\quad.
$$

Hence, taking expectation on the both side
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2a_i^2 \ge n^{-\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\right)\ge 1-\sqrt{en^{-\alpha}}
$$

Now, we can lower bound the denominator of $L$ with high probability $1-\sqrt{en^{-\alpha}}$:
$$
L\le n^{\alpha/2}\frac{a_1X_1}{\sqrt{\sum_i a_i^2}}=n^{\alpha/2}\frac{e^{-2\lambda_1t}X_1}{\sqrt{\sum_i e^{-4\lambda_it}}}
$$

But this upper bound does not work for my question. So I want to get a tight upper bound as $\alpha=0$.

**Can we get more tighter upper bound with high probability? For example,
$$
L\le \frac{e^{-2\lambda_1t}}{\sqrt{\sum_i e^{-4\lambda_it}}}
$$**

---

Another way: I try to consider upper bound the difference between $L_1(t)$ and $L_j(t)$ (here I choose the subscript $i$ dependent on $X_i$):

$$
L_1(t)-L_j(t)=\frac{a_1X_1-a_jX_j}{\sqrt{\sum_i a^2_iX^2_i}}=\frac{e^{-2\lambda_1 t}(1-e^{-2t(\lambda_j-\lambda_1)})X_1+e^{-2\lambda_j t}(X_1-X_j)}{\sqrt{\sum_i a^2_iX^2_i}}
$$

Can we upper bound $L_1(t)-L_j(t)$ for every $j$ to get our desired result?

Comment: The constant factor in the bound in the linked answer does not depend on the $a_i$'s there. So, the same bound will hold in the present case.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I check the proof but he assume that $\sum_i a_i=1$ which is not true in my case... Can we still prove that?

Comment: @IosifPinelis If that concentration inequality is true for my case, I update my thought and questions. Do you think that works?

Comment: The condition $\sum_i a_i=1$ was assumed in that answer without loss of generality. The first displayed inequality in the answer holds for any $a_i>0$.

Comment: Ok, I see! So we can take $\epsilon=1/n$, and get my second displayed inequality?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Also, how about my updated question? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can make this substitution.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thanks! Since $\lambda_i$ are random variables following semi-circle law, can we remove this condition probability in that inequality?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Can we just take expectation on the both side?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the condition.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Oh... I just found a issue. My $X_i\sim N(0, 1/n)$ but not $N(0,1)$.

Comment: What I said previously was assuming that the $X_i$'s were (i) iid $N(0,1)$ as before and (ii) independent of $A$. If (ii) fails to hold, you need to specify the dependence. As for (i), if you replace $N(0,1)$, then it should easy to show that there is no anti-concentration.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thanks. I update my question now. Do you think that right?

Comment: @IosifPinelis So there is no anti-concentration inequality for $N(0,1/n)$ random variables?

Comment: After your last edit, the question seems to have become incomprehensible. I suggest you take time (like a few days) to think about what you actually want and then carefully present your question.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Does this question make sense now?